# Pechkin Html -> PDF With Table Of Contents

Tags: c#, pdf, pechkin

I am having a very difficult time adding a table of contents to my generated pdfs utilizing Pechkin.  I have tried specifying a location to the XSLT file to use, however, nothing happens.  I have tried to manually create my own TOC but was unable to get the page numbers to match up accordingly.

Has anyone been able to successfully generate a pdf with a table of contents utilizing Pechkin?  If so, can anyone provide a code snippet or guidance on how to begin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a known issue with Pechkin but you may want to look at this http://alistapart.com/article/boom#section7

Comment: and this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipxslt/index.html